# Angular2 Posting List of complex type to MVC action

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I got in to a problem where I need to post a list of complex type from Angular2 to MVC action. The problem is that I always get null for the parameter when I pass array. It works perfectly if a single object. Please look at the code below:
The first action gets the posted object, but the second always get null.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Submit(Parent parent)
    {
        return Json(new { data = "some message" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

the following gets null

```
   [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Submit(List<Parent> parents)
    {
        return Json(new { data = "some message" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }     
    public bool? IsCompleted { get; set; }   
    public string UserResponse { get; set; }    
    public Dictionary<int, bool> SelectedItemsIds { get; set; }      

    public virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AnotherChild> Representations { get; set; }
    public List<Parent> Drived { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }

}
```

And this is what I try:

```
submita(): Observable<string> {
    let headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
    var resp = this.http.post('/Home/Submit', this.parents, options)
        .map((response: Response) => <string>response.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    return resp;
}
```

this.parents is array of parent which has the same properties as the server side class
Any help will be appreciated
Please note, the issue appears to be on the size of the data I'm posting to the server. Any ideas where I can increase that? 
I tried the following in web config but it didn't fix it.

```html
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

Comment: url is **'/Home/Submit1'** in angular2 and action name is submit in controller

Comment: I have edited it. I was testing different scenarios

Comment: can you perform console.log of this.parents and share the image or values??

Comment: It's just an array of Parent type which has complex objects and arrays of complex objects as properties. I have checked that it has values on the client side.

Comment: The issue appears to be on the size of the data I'm posting, I have edited my post. 
Now the issue is where to increase the size limitation. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: increasing the MaxJsonLength of JavaScriptSerializer on the server side fixed my issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Glad It helped!